# Dynamodb batch-write-item DeleteRequest request item structure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I call

```
aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://./TestDelete.json
```

with the file

```
{
  "TheTable" :
[
  {
    "DeleteRequest": "{\"Key\": {\"PK\": {\"S\": \"foo\"}, \"SK\":{\"S\":\"bar\"}}} "
  }
]
}
```

Which yields the error

```
Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.TheTable[0].DeleteRequest, value:
{
  "TheTable" :
[
  {"Key": 
    {
      "PK": {"S": "foo"},
      "SK": {"S": "bar"}
    }
  }
]
}
type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>
```

The JSON looks valid to me, I am defining that the key values as strings.  I feel that I'm missing something obvious, although https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html isn't entirely clear.

Comment: Don't json-stringify the delete request within your JSON file. Just present it as  `"DeleteRequest": { "Key": { "PK" : { "S" : "foo" }, "SK": { "S": "bar" } } }`

Comment: I changed it, and it returns `Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter`

Comment: Can you update your post with the new JSON file contents?

Comment: `Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 5 column 29 (char 52) JSON received: {  "TheTable" :
[
    {
        "DeleteRequest": "{"Key": {"PK": {"S": "foo"}}, "SK":{"S":"bar"}} "
    }
]
}
`

Comment: The original JSON passes a linter, and the CLI understands it.  It just doesn't like it.

Comment: Why do you have a double-quote before `{"Key"`? Make the DeleteRequest value a dict, not a string containing a jsonified dict.

Comment: You may be on to something, I think the nesting is semantically wrong.

Comment: It works, thanks.  The problem now is that I can't get the query output from dynamodb scan in the correct form.  It was the one doing the extra escaping.

Comment: So, you have a bash script (or perhaps PowerShell script) that's taking the output of `aws dynamodb scan ...` and passing that into `aws dynamodb batch-write-item`? You should probably include how you're doing that in the post. Do you have an option to do this in Python or must it be a shell script?

Answer (score 0):

You have the DeleteRequest wrapped as a string when it should be a JSON object, which you can also tell from the exception: `type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>`

TestDelete.json should look like this:

```
{
    "TheTable": [
        {
            "DeleteRequest":  {
                "Key": {
                    "PK": {
                        "S": "foo"
                    },
                    "SK": {
                        "S": "bar"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using a windows machine and need the escape characters, be sure to escape properly, as you are currently passing in a string.

Comment: Yeah, my eyes were getting crossed from trying to find the problem.  They glided over the quotes around the DeleteRequest value, and json lint gave me false confidence.  I gave up trying to get JMESPath to output what I needed; I fell back to the text output option and used a lot of sed.